# Glassfish 3.1.2.2 JDBC Realm Configuration issue

Tags: java, jdbc, glassfish, jdbcrealm

I am trying to configure JDBC Realm in Glassfish 3.1.2.2 but it does not work at all.
I have already created **Connection Pool** and **JNDI mapping**. Ping to database is also successful.

Here is my Realm configuration setting page:

[image]

Here is the entire stack trace:

> [#|2014-08-26T21:03:42.357+0200|SEVERE|glassfish3.1.2|javax.enterprise.system.std.com.sun.enterprise.server.logging|_ThreadID=94;_ThreadName=Thread-2;|javax.servlet.ServletException:
>   Exception thrown while attempting to authenticate for user: admin     at
>   org.apache.catalina.connector.Request.login(Request.java:1970)    at
>   org.apache.catalina.connector.Request.login(Request.java:1901)    at
>   org.apache.catalina.connector.RequestFacade.login(RequestFacade.java:1146)
>     at com.survey.ui.LoginController.login(LoginController.java:62)     at
>   sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)   at
>   sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
>     at
>   sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
>     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)     at
>   com.sun.el.parser.AstValue.invoke(AstValue.java:254)  at
>   com.sun.el.MethodExpressionImpl.invoke(MethodExpressionImpl.java:302)
>     at
>   org.jboss.weld.util.el.ForwardingMethodExpression.invoke(ForwardingMethodExpression.java:39)
>     at
>   org.jboss.weld.el.WeldMethodExpression.invoke(WeldMethodExpression.java:50)
>     at
>   com.sun.faces.facelets.el.TagMethodExpression.invoke(TagMethodExpression.java:105)
>     at
>   javax.faces.component.MethodBindingMethodExpressionAdapter.invoke(MethodBindingMethodExpressionAdapter.java:88)
>     at
>   com.sun.faces.application.ActionListenerImpl.processAction(ActionListenerImpl.java:102)
>     at javax.faces.component.UICommand.broadcast(UICommand.java:315)    at
>   javax.faces.component.UIViewRoot.broadcastEvents(UIViewRoot.java:794)
>     at
>   javax.faces.component.UIViewRoot.processApplication(UIViewRoot.java:1259)
>     at
>   com.sun.faces.lifecycle.InvokeApplicationPhase.execute(InvokeApplicationPhase.java:81)
>     at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.Phase.doPhase(Phase.java:101)    at
>   com.sun.faces.lifecycle.LifecycleImpl.execute(LifecycleImpl.java:118)
>     at javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet.service(FacesServlet.java:593)   at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.service(StandardWrapper.java:1550)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:343)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:217)
>     at
>   org.primefaces.webapp.filter.FileUploadFilter.doFilter(FileUploadFilter.java:98)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:256)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:217)
>     at
>   com.survey.general.servlet.filter.CacheResources.doFilter(CacheResources.java:51)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:256)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:217)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:279)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:175)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.StandardPipeline.doInvoke(StandardPipeline.java:655)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.StandardPipeline.invoke(StandardPipeline.java:595)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:161)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.doService(CoyoteAdapter.java:331)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:231)
>     at
>   com.sun.enterprise.v3.services.impl.ContainerMapper$AdapterCallable.call(ContainerMapper.java:317)
>     at
>   com.sun.enterprise.v3.services.impl.ContainerMapper.service(ContainerMapper.java:195)
>     at
>   com.sun.grizzly.http.ProcessorTask.invokeAdapter(ProcessorTask.java:860)
>     at
>   com.sun.grizzly.http.ProcessorTask.doProcess(ProcessorTask.java:757)
>     at
>   com.sun.grizzly.http.ProcessorTask.process(ProcessorTask.java:1056)
>     at
>   com.sun.grizzly.http.DefaultProtocolFilter.execute(DefaultProtocolFilter.java:229)
>     at
>   com.sun.grizzly.DefaultProtocolChain.executeProtocolFilter(DefaultProtocolChain.java:137)
>     at
>   com.sun.grizzly.DefaultProtocolChain.execute(DefaultProtocolChain.java:104)
>     at
>   com.sun.grizzly.DefaultProtocolChain.execute(DefaultProtocolChain.java:90)
>     at
>   com.sun.grizzly.http.HttpProtocolChain.execute(HttpProtocolChain.java:79)
>     at
>   com.sun.grizzly.ProtocolChainContextTask.doCall(ProtocolChainContextTask.java:54)
>     at
>   com.sun.grizzly.SelectionKeyContextTask.call(SelectionKeyContextTask.java:59)
>     at com.sun.grizzly.ContextTask.run(ContextTask.java:71)     at
>   com.sun.grizzly.util.AbstractThreadPool$Worker.doWork(AbstractThreadPool.java:532)
>     at
>   com.sun.grizzly.util.AbstractThreadPool$Worker.run(AbstractThreadPool.java:513)
>     at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:744) Caused by:
>   javax.servlet.ServletException: Failed login while attempting to
>   authenticate user: admin  at
>   org.apache.catalina.connector.Request.login(Request.java:1941)    ... 53
>   more

Comment: Can you elaborate on the "*does not work*" part?

Comment: I am getting this **Caused by: javax.servlet.ServletException: Failed login while attempting to authenticate user: admin**

Comment: Please post the entire stack trace and part of the code it points to.

Comment: @PM77-1 I have edited my question and added stack trace. Actually I am using **Basic Authentication** method and when I am trying to login with username password using HttpServletRequest request.login method gives an error